# Configure database in phpstorm for a laravel project

Tags: database, laravel, vagrant, configure, homestead

I'm working on a iMac (Sierra) with phpstorm & Vagrant box laravel/homestead

I try to configure the database in the IDE but each time it failed and it said, an idea?

```
Connection to cmsineria@localhost failed: SSH: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.
SSH: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

[image: database param 1]

[image: database param 2]

Comment: Paste the `.env` configuration file.

Comment: Show your Homestead.yaml

Comment: you need to have DB_HOST as 0.0.0.0

Comment: nop doesn't work, it can't be 0.0.0.0

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVE --> https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2017/03/how-to-manipulate-the-mysql-database-of-your-vagrant-from-phpstorm/ --> Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Macbook Air Sierra using `MAMP`.

By default, `MAMP` use `port` **8889** for `MySQL`. Try to change `port` **3306** to **8889** in `General`.